# Color coding ListPlot according to list of strings

Tags: plotting, color

I have a simple scatterplot of (X,Y) data points from different animals. I would like to color code the individual point according to a list of strings containing the corresponding animal order:

{"Proboscidea", "Proboscidea", "Proboscidea", "Hyracoidea","Primates", "Primates", "Primates", "Rodentia", "Soricomorpha", "Chiroptera", "Carnivora", "Carnivora", "Carnivora","Perissodactyla", "Perissodactyla", "Artiodactyla", "Artiodactyla","Artiodactyla", "Artiodactyla", "Artiodactyla", "Artiodactyla","Artiodactyla", "Artiodactyla", "Cetacea", "Cetacea", "Cetacea","Cetacea", "Cetacea", "Cetacea", "Cetacea", "Cetacea", "Cetacea", "Cetacea", "Cetacea", "Cetacea"}

This has to be in such a way that all "Primates" get the same color, all "Carnivora" get the same color, and onwards.

Moreover, I would like to display a plot Legend showing the color code.

The solution must be able to handle a random number of different "orders" since this varies between my datasets.

Answer (score 2):

Generate some data

```
orders = {"Proboscidea", "Proboscidea", "Proboscidea", "Hyracoidea", 
   "Primates", "Primates", "Primates", "Rodentia", "Soricomorpha", 
   "Chiroptera", "Carnivora", "Carnivora", "Carnivora", 
   "Perissodactyla", "Perissodactyla", "Artiodactyla", "Artiodactyla",
    "Artiodactyla", "Artiodactyla", "Artiodactyla", "Artiodactyla", 
   "Artiodactyla", "Artiodactyla", "Cetacea", "Cetacea", "Cetacea", 
   "Cetacea", "Cetacea", "Cetacea", "Cetacea", "Cetacea", "Cetacea", 
   "Cetacea", "Cetacea", "Cetacea"} // DeleteDuplicates

SeedRandom[1];
data = Table[{RandomReal[10], RandomReal[10], RandomChoice@orders}, 20]
```

Group the data by order and plot

```
data // GroupBy[Last -> Most] // ListPlot
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Suggest you also sort, e.g., `data // SortBy[Last] // GroupBy[Last -> Most] // ListPlot`

Comment: @agger Was my answer helpful? If not, how can it be improved? If it was, please consider accepting my answer. Thanks!